# Count total number of bindings in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

Is there some kind of variable in Knockout JS that keeps track of the total number of bindings in the entire DOM?

I have a complex application and I want to see if my cleanup/destruction code does it's job or not. So clicking between views and see the total number of bindings would really help.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you whether or not there is an out-of-the-box way to do that, but if there isn't, you could simply overwrite the `init` function of each binding handler in such a way that you add the binding name to an array, for example.

Then you can delegate the `init` to the original handler. Since there aren't too many binding handlers built in, this shouldn't be too overwhelming to do in case there isn't an out-of-the-box solution. You can find a working example of this in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doxpt83h/1/).

Basically every time a binding is initialized, you add the binding name to an array. You could simply increment a counter as well but that wouldn't tell you too much as to what actual bindings there exist. Additionally, if you observe the array being logged to the console in the provided fiddle, you'll notice that the actual bindings are a bit higher than what you explicitly create (for eg., `evennt` bindings as a side effect of creating a `click` binding, etc). To this end, adding the actual binding names to an array is a bit more telling solution.

Make sure you decrement the value of the counter when a [binding is get rid of](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-disposal.html). This is what the `ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(...)` does.

Also pay attention to the order in which the scripts are referenced. This code should run **after each and every binding handler that you want to use/keep track of has been imported, but before any actual binding is created**. So in the simplest case, import the ko JavaScript file, then possibly all your custom bindings, and then a script file that contains this code. Any binding should only be applied once these are done.

Comment: Don't forget to return the value of `originalHandler.init`, since some bindings need to return `{ controlsDescendantBindings: true }`